# Laravel 7x API no sending Mail Alert

Tags: php, laravel, api, model-view-controller, alert

when I try with Postman or Insomnia to make the POST to store the email with the data does not ARRIVE I do not understand why.

I have the following fields:

```
public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('polls', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->text('now');
                $table->json('paramJson');
                $table->enum('status', ['a', 'b', 'c','d'])->default('a');
            });
        }
```

Poll model:

```
protected $fillable = ['now'];
protected $casts = ['paramJson' => 'array'];
```

PollsController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $poll = request->all();
        if($poll['status']=='b')
        {
            Mail::to('example@....com')->send(new NotifyPoll($poll));
        }

        return response()->json(Poll::create($poll), 201);
    }
```

Mail/NotifyPoll

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NotifyPoll extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->itemPoll = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('.......@inbox.mailtrap.io')->subject('Error Poll')->view('mail.notifyErrorPoll',['mail_data'=>$this->itemPoll]);
    }
}
```

Insomnia side I do not receive errors, but unfortunately the mail does not arrive.

Comment: Have you tried making the poll data a public property on your `Mailable` class? `public $poll;` and then use `__construct($poll)` so that it's available to the template?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed out the `protected $itemPoll` in `NotifyPoll` class. Also, check your log file to get the error stack. It helps a lot when debugging.

Comment: I think I don't understand what you mean by: "I think you missed out the protected $itemPoll in NotifyPoll". where do i find the log file?

Comment: @Gianmarco Gagliardi you didn't declare the `$itemPoll` variable in the class. The log file can be found in storage/logs

Comment: ok I should do public $itemPoll. I did not understand what it is for ?. my problem was related to the configuration side ENV sender